# what replaces init(name:float:) now that it has been deprecated

Tags: swift, swift3, init

I'm getting a warning that `init(name:float:)` has been deprecated with Swift3.  Does anyone know what has replaced it?

The problem came up in a shader:

```
SKUniform(name: "size", 
    float:GLKVector3Make(
        Float(self.frame.size.width), 
        Float(self.frame.size.height), 0)),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [iOS 10 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html):

> iOS 10 deprecates several APIs, including:
>
> ...
>
> Several `SKUniform` symbols related to floating point values. Instead, use methods such as `initWithName:vectorFloat2:` and `uniformWithName:matrixFloat2x2:`, as appropriate.

For example:

```
SKUniform(name: "size", 
          vectorFloat2:vector2(
            Float(self.frame.size.width), 
            Float(self.frame.size.height)
          ))
```

Comment: Thanks.  So you are suggesting 'SKUniform(initWithName: "size", vectorFloat2: Float(self.frame.size.width), Float(self.frame.size.height)),'

Comment: I've tried the change above but get a new error: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'SKUniform' with an argument list of type '(initWithName: String, vectorFloat2: Float, Float)'"  Can anyone suggest how to code the new methods available in Swift3?

Comment: Retype the function `SKUniform(name: "size", vec)` and use code completion to get the suggestions.

Comment: That is what I tried.  Within SKUniform(), there were no code completions.  The SKUniform itself is part of an array of uniforms 'shader.uniforms = [...]'  Perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: Paste `SKUniform(name: "size", ve)` and type `c`

Comment: To try a simpler approach, I've added 'SKUniform(name: "size", vector_float2: (200, 300))' This returns an error: Argument labels '(name:, _:)' do not match any available overloads.  I tried a different syntax without the colon after 'float2'.  That still returns the same error.

Comment: Thanks.  I see how it works now.  I was getting vector_float2 when the code suggestion started to work.  Now it works with your updated answer above :-)